# Organizing large Netflix queues

Tags: netflix

The queue in Netflix is pretty hard to keep organized. I like to organize the instant watch queue in particular, because we view the queue on our TV through the Wii interface, which is incredibly hard to navigate through.

Is there any other way to do this aside from using the drag-and-drop or the renumber interface provided? Both are impractical for large queues.

Edit: I'm using Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Firefox (and maybe Chrome, now too) and have the Greasemonkey extension installed, there's a script that allows you to do a lot more organization with your queue:

[Netflix Queue Sorter for Greasemonkey](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/35183)

Comment: Alas, there's no greasemonkey for Chrome. Maybe soon... this is a good answer for Firefox users, though.

Comment: @neilfein: There are other options available as well, such as: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/plcnnpdmhobdfbponjpedobekiogmbco# or converting the script to a bookmarklet (which means you need to manually invoke it, which sounds reasonable for this case)